# Postgres SQL vs Python - GROUP BY Performance

Tags: python, postgresql, performance

Having a table "Transaction" that has:

1. id (id auto increment)
2. title (text)
3. description (text)
4. vendor (text)

It is asked to have a list of 100 most used words in any of these and their permutations (combinations of 2 words - having their reverse permutation ignored [e.g. permutations of A and B would be AA, AB, BB, BA and we want to exclude cases where A=B and A>B]). For example, if a transaction would have:

1. title = PayPal payment
2. description =
3. vendor = Sony

We would expect to have a distinct list of words [PayPal, payment, Sony]. Please note that in some cases the word might have punctuation and we have to remove those.

So the expected result would be:
[Paypal, payment, Sony, Payment PayPal, Paypal Sony, Payment Sony]

I made a SQL query for Postgres to do this and the performance was terrible:

```
WITH
    oneWord as (SELECT t.id, a.word, t.gross_amount
                FROM (SELECT * FROM transaction t) t,
                    unnest(string_to_array(regexp_replace(regexp_replace(
                        concat(t.vendor, ' ',
                             t.title, ' ',
                             t.description),
                      '[\s+]', ' ', 'g'), '[[:punct:]]', '', 'g'), ' ',
                '')) as a(word)
                WHERE a.word NOT IN (SELECT word FROM wordcloudexclusion)
    ),
    oneWordDistinct as (SELECT id, word, gross_amount FROM oneWord),
    twoWord as (SELECT a.id,CONCAT(a.word, ' ', b.word) as word, a.gross_amount
                from oneWord a, oneWord b
                where a.id = b.id and a < b),
    allWord as (SELECT oneWordDistinct.id as id, oneWordDistinct.word as word, oneWordDistinct.gross_amount as gross_amount
                from oneWordDistinct
                union all
                SELECT twoWord.id as id, twoWord.word as word, twoWord.gross_amount as gross_amount
                from twoWord)
SELECT a.word, count(a.id) FROM allWord a GROUP BY a.word ORDER BY 2 DESC LIMIT 100;
```

And doing the same in python as follows:

```
text_stats = {}
transactions = (SELECT id, title, description, vendor, gross_amount FROM transactions)
for [id, title, description, vendor, amount] in list(transactions):

    text = " ".join(filter(None, [title, description, vendor]))
    text_without_punctuation = re.sub(r"[.!?,]+", "", text)
    text_without_tabs = re.sub(
        r"[\n\t\r]+", " ", text_without_punctuation
    ).strip(" ")
    words = list(set(filter(None, text_without_tabs.split(" "))))
    for a_word in words:
        if a_word not in excluded_words:
            if not text_stats.get(a_word):
                text_stats[a_word] = {
                    "count": 1,
                    "amount": amount,
                    "word": a_word,
                }
            else:
                text_stats[a_word]["count"] += 1
                text_stats[a_word]["amount"] += amount
            for b_word in words:
                if b_word > a_word:
                    sentence = a_word + " " + b_word
                    if not text_stats.get(sentence):
                        text_stats[sentence] = {
                            "count": 1,
                            "amount": amount,
                            "word": sentence,
                        }
                    else:
                        text_stats[sentence]["count"] += 1
                        text_stats[sentence]["amount"] += amount
```

My question is: Is there a way to improve the performance of the SQL so that it isn't completely obliterated by python? Currently on a 20k record transaction table it takes python **~6-8 seconds** and the SQL query **1 min and 10 seconds**.

Here is the SQL explain analyse:

```
Limit  (cost=260096.60..260096.85 rows=100 width=40) (actual time=63928.627..63928.639 rows=100 loops=1)
  CTE oneword
    ->  Nested Loop  (cost=16.76..2467.36 rows=44080 width=44) (actual time=1.875..126.778 rows=132851 loops=1)
          ->  Seq Scan on gc_api_transaction t  (cost=0.00..907.80 rows=8816 width=110) (actual time=0.018..4.176 rows=8816 loops=1)
                Filter: (company_id = 2)
                Rows Removed by Filter: 5648
          ->  Function Scan on unnest a_2  (cost=16.76..16.89 rows=5 width=32) (actual time=0.010..0.013 rows=15 loops=8816)
                Filter: (NOT (hashed SubPlan 1))
                Rows Removed by Filter: 2
                SubPlan 1
                  ->  Seq Scan on gc_api_wordcloudexclusion  (cost=0.00..15.40 rows=540 width=118) (actual time=1.498..1.500 rows=7 loops=1)
  ->  Sort  (cost=257629.24..257629.74 rows=200 width=40) (actual time=63911.588..63911.594 rows=100 loops=1)
        Sort Key: (count(oneword.id)) DESC
        Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 36kB
        ->  HashAggregate  (cost=257619.60..257621.60 rows=200 width=40) (actual time=23000.982..63803.962 rows=1194618 loops=1)
              Group Key: oneword.word
              Batches: 85  Memory Usage: 4265kB  Disk Usage: 113344kB
              ->  Append  (cost=0.00..241207.14 rows=3282491 width=36) (actual time=1.879..5443.143 rows=2868282 loops=1)
                    ->  CTE Scan on oneword  (cost=0.00..881.60 rows=44080 width=36) (actual time=1.878..579.936 rows=132851 loops=1)
"                    ->  Subquery Scan on ""*SELECT* 2""  (cost=13085.79..223913.09 rows=3238411 width=36) (actual time=2096.116..4698.727 rows=2735431 loops=1)"
                          ->  Merge Join  (cost=13085.79..191528.98 rows=3238411 width=44) (actual time=2096.114..4492.451 rows=2735431 loops=1)
                                Merge Cond: (a_1.id = b.id)
                                Join Filter: (a_1.* < b.*)
                                Rows Removed by Join Filter: 2879000
                                ->  Sort  (cost=6542.90..6653.10 rows=44080 width=96) (actual time=1088.083..1202.200 rows=132851 loops=1)
                                      Sort Key: a_1.id
                                      Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 8512kB
                                      ->  CTE Scan on oneword a_1  (cost=0.00..881.60 rows=44080 width=96) (actual time=3.904..101.754 rows=132851 loops=1)
                                ->  Materialize  (cost=6542.90..6763.30 rows=44080 width=96) (actual time=1007.989..1348.317 rows=5614422 loops=1)
                                      ->  Sort  (cost=6542.90..6653.10 rows=44080 width=96) (actual time=1007.984..1116.011 rows=132851 loops=1)
                                            Sort Key: b.id
                                            Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 8712kB
                                            ->  CTE Scan on oneword b  (cost=0.00..881.60 rows=44080 width=96) (actual time=0.014..20.998 rows=132851 loops=1)
Planning Time: 0.537 ms
JIT:
  Functions: 49
"  Options: Inlining false, Optimization false, Expressions true, Deforming true"
"  Timing: Generation 6.119 ms, Inlining 0.000 ms, Optimization 2.416 ms, Emission 17.764 ms, Total 26.299 ms"
Execution Time: 63945.718 ms
```

Postgresql verison: PostgreSQL 14.5 (Debian 14.5-1.pgdg110+1) on aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 10.2.1-6) 10.2.1 20210110, 64-bit

Comment: Which Postgres version are you using?

Comment: Won't make a difference, but: `FROM (SELECT * FROM transaction t)` can be simplified to `from transaction t`.  And the CTE `oneWordDistinct` is completely useless

Comment: version: PostgreSQL 14.5

Comment: the `oneWordDistinct` is supposed to distinct words, not implemented in this scenario yet.

Comment: Python code is not compilable. Interesting it took those few seconds. How are you timing? With Bash's `time`: `time python myscript.py` and `time psql -U myuser-d mydb -f myscript.sql`?

Comment: Python code is not compilable most likely because `transactions = (SELECT *...)` was just a pseudo-code for what is actually there querying the database for those results.
I timed the SQL query in a Django API request through postman.
I timed the python code the same way.
I also executed the query in Intellij and it took about the same time.
Both produce the same output.
I was also impressed by the difference in time execution (started suspecting I did something wrong in the query)

Comment: The difference in time execution is so clearly different that I don't even need to time it to know which one I am going to use until I find a better solution.

Comment: Depending on your temp_buffers(probably it is okay) you can use temporary table or materialized view instead of CTE. Because, appearently, you are using lots of disk space and the most of the time was spent for hashaggregating and sorting. There is also underestimation(it was expecting 200 rows but it got 1194618). You might even think creating index on that temporary table.

Comment: Yes. I thought of that. But materialized views are supposed to be performant in case the table is updated rarely…

Comment: I will try it and come back when I got something more concrete abou materialized view. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For databases index is everytink but you are using like `unnest`,`string_to_array`, `regexp_replace`, `concat` methods. Those are not index familier.

So for best performance, you need to create a `Table` like `trancastion_words` which it will include columns like `transaction_id, word`. Which including words of `transactions`. And also you need to create `triggers` which `listening` transaction table, it will `listen` for `every insert delete and modify` for `refresh` `transaction_words` `which releated` with those record.

After it you need to create `index` for `performanced` joining `transaction_words` to `itself`.

My advice, at everytime fetch like this, if you create `materialized view` which `refreshing periodicly` it will better for big systems. Via this, your application will not wait db for executations. Currently your system `just` have 20k record, you cant't feel `memory consume` of like `string_to_array` methods, but when datas increased like `millions or billions` datas, your sql can't finish because of those methods memory consumes.